# Correct handling of persistent files for readonly rootfs

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I want my rootfs to be readonly. As far as I found out there a few measures that need to be done to achieve that before setting the `"readonly-rootfs"` in `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES`.
Right now, I'm trying to move the files `passwd`, `shadow`, `gshadow` and `group` from `/etc` in the rootfs to a persistent storage, namely `/data/etc` and how the following recipe which basically does the job:

```
ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "move_to_persistent;"

WANT_PERSISTENT = " \ 
    shadow \
    gshadow  \
    passwd  \
    group  \
"

PERSISTENT_TARGET_DIRECTORY = "${D}"

# Testing a different location here in rootfs with the same result
# as described in the stack overflow question
# PERSISTENT_TARGET_DIRECTORY = "${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/test"

FROM = "${IMAGE_ROOTFS}${sysconfdir}"
TO = "${PERSISTENT_TARGET_DIRECTORY}/data${sysconfdir}"

move_to_persistent () {
    install -d ${TO}

    for fn in ${WANT_PERSISTENT}; do
        mv ${FROM}/$fn ${TO}/$fn
        ln -r -s ${TO}/$fn ${FROM}/$fn
    done
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error that `useradd command did not succeed.`.
And in fact when I check the ownership of the moved files I see my host user as owner there:

```
[...]/my-image/1.0-r0/image/data/etc/
total 16
-rw-r--r-- 1 marius marius  639 Mai 19 12:47 group
-rw------- 1 marius marius  536 Mai 19 12:47 gshadow
-rw-r--r-- 1 marius marius 1025 Mai 19 12:47 passwd
-rw------- 1 marius marius  649 Mai 19 12:47 shadow
```

Now, the question is: How do I set or preserve the correct ownership of the files and do you see other problems ahead with this approach?
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply symlinking /etc/passwd to writable storage does not work because of the checks made by passwd and other tools. There are a couple of things that would work, which I will mention below. But before that, using passwd implies that you are using passwords for authentication, which is not the most secure way of doing it. Maybe you could use a certificate of some sort (as with ssh keys) or some kind of web authentication

Anyhow, here are two ways to get passwd to work...

1. Use a bind mount

Copy /etc to a directory in a writable partition, named /data in the example. Note that you have to copy the whole of /etc because passwd needs to create several files in there during the update

Do this once (at build time)

```
cp -a /etc /data
```

Do this at boot time

```
mount --bind /data/etc /etc
```

2. Use overlayfs

Build your kernel with CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS. Then you can do something like
this:

Do this once (at build time)

```
mkdir -p /data/etc/work /data/etc/upper
```

Do this at boot time

```
mount -t overlay \
      -o lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/data/etc/upper,workdir=/data/etc/work \
       overlay /etc
```

Any changes to /etc are actually recorded in /data/etc/upper, but will
appear to be in /etc.

I am not giving OpenEmbedded recipes to implement either of these solutions here because the changes are pretty trivial but dependent on the exact configuration you are building

Comment: A matching fstab entry for the overlayfs would be:
`overlay /etc overlay defaults,nofail,lowerdir=/etc,upperdir=/data/etc/upper,workdir=/data/etc/work 0 2`

Answer (score 0):

After some research and investigation it seems that the recipe is doing what it is supposed to do. BUT as discussed in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/491033/cannot-useradd-adduser-when-etc-passwd-shadow-group-are-symlink-debian-squee/491111#491111?newreg=1d9634a1bfdc435a89b52752d8ffe5bd) `passwd` explicitly avoids following symbolic links for security reasons. Thus, the problem lies elsewhere.